# How to use StringUtils.substringsBetween();?

Tags: java, string, substring

can someone demonstrate how to work with StringUtils.substringsBetween() method in java?

Comment: Do you really mean substringsBetween (plural) or substringBetween (singular)? You're asking for substrings but the answer marked as correct is for substring.

Comment: Please see the documentation http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#substringsBetween

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
String foo = "<foo>foo</foo>";
String bar = StringUtils.substringBetween(foo, "<foo>", "</foo>");
```

The variable **bar** will have the *String* **"foo"**.

Comment: is there any simple method which will handle **substringBetween** case-insensitive opening and closing strings, I understand that I can convert the whole string into lower case and search in lower case but is there easier solution ?

Answer (score 6):

This one? Pretty clear from the [JavaDoc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#substringsBetween(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)):

> Searches a String for substrings delimited by a start and end tag,
>   returning all matching substrings in an array.
>
> A null input String returns null. A null open/close returns null (no
>   match). An empty ("") open/close returns null (no match).
>
> ```
> StringUtils.substringsBetween("[a][b][c]", "[", "]") = ["a","b","c"]
> StringUtils.substringsBetween(null, *, *)            = null
> StringUtils.substringsBetween(*, null, *)            = null
> StringUtils.substringsBetween(*, *, null)            = null
> StringUtils.substringsBetween("", "[", "]")          = []
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
String str = "begin middle end";        
str = StringUtils.substringBetween(str, "begin", "end");  //str =" middle "
```

Comment: -1. Your code does not compile. You declared String to the variable "str" twice.

Answer (score 1):

```
String bigString = "Quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
String smallString = org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.subStringBetween(bigString, "brown", "the");

System.out.println(smallString);

output - 

jumps over
```

Comment: Output:  fox jumps over

Answer (score 1):

It is clearly explained in the StringUtils API documentation :
[Apache Docs](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html)

Basically this method takes 2 inputs :
substringBetween(String verificationStr, String tag)
It returns the string present in verificationStr that is enclosed by the tag on both the sides (i.e left & right). It returns null if there is no match

eg 1: verificationStr = "abstackab"
tag = "ab"
result = "stack" ==> since the string stack was enclosed on both the sides by the string "ab"

eg 2: verificationStr = "abstackak"
tag = "ab"
result = null ==> since there is no string that is enclosed on both the sides by the string "ab"

Comment: Link from 2012 broken

Answer (score 0):

I think StringUtils is not part of Java, it is part of apache. Here is example for

```
String title = StringUtils.substringBetween(testHtml, "<title>", "</title>");
```